# Display Image using grideview in android application

Tags: android

I try out many codes for display images in gridview but the application gone close in emulator. Here is my code...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        
    final GridView ObjGrid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    ObjGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));        
}
```

And ImageAdapter class is as above

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

int[] images = new int[]{
        R.drawable.pic1,
        R.drawable.pic2,
        R.drawable.pic3,
        R.drawable.pic4,
        R.drawable.pic5,
        R.drawable.pic6
    };
private Context cont;
public ImageAdapter(Context applicationContext) {
    cont = applicationContext;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View ConvertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ImageView iv;
    if(ConvertView == null)
    {
        iv = new ImageView(cont);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180, 180));
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        iv.setPadding(0, 8, 8, 8);          
    }
    else
    {           
        iv=(ImageView)ConvertView;
    }
    iv.setImageResource(images[arg0]);
    return null;
}
```

}

Please give me solution, and if there is any possibility to give project file to downlode then it will be very help full to me...
Thank you

Comment: You should consider improving your question, because right now I don't understand anything.

Comment: Also what does this have to do with asp.net?

Answer (score 2):

You are returning null in the getView method. You should return there the view (in your case, the ImageView you are generating), not null!